# How can I bootstrap with weights in "randomForestSRC"?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I would like to bootstrap with weights in random survival forest (randomForestSRC package) because I have a case-cohort study design.

Please let me know how to add the "weights" option in this analysis.

Thank you.

Here is my code below. (implemented with sample data)

```
install.packages("randomForestSRC")
library(randomForestSRC)
data(pbc, package="randomForestSRC")
data <- na.omit(pbc)

rsf <- rfsrc(Surv(days, status)~., 
             data=data, 
             ntree=500, 
             tree.err=T,
             importance=T,
             proximity=T)
```

Comment: Why not bootstrap the data, instead? Use `boot::boot`. You would need to specify what statistic you wanted. You should post data (given) and a clear description of the desired result (not seen) when you want a worked example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the bootstrap related options in the man page for rfsrc() on CRAN.  In the CRAN package, the option "samp" allows you to explicitly specify the bootstrap for every tree. Hence, you would populate an n x ntree matrix of indices based on your weights.  A slightly more pictorial depiction of how ntree, the  bootstrap option, sample type, sample size, and sample all interact is given on our GitHub page:

https://kogalur.github.io/randomForestSRC/javadoc/index.html